# Im using Azure B2C for my Web application authentication, and i want to have a direct link to the signup page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Im using Azure B2C for my Web application authentication, when the user click on login it take the user to the login page and the user can login there and its configured via the authentication of the applicaiton. but i want the have a "signup" link on the home page when the user clicks it should directly take to the signup page (rather than going to the sigin page and then by clicking signup link). can someone suggest a way. btw im using b2c user flows for signin and signup

i tired this url , but does not seems to be working
https://tenantID.b2clogin.com/tenantID.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=policyId

Comment: You can create [**sign-up user flow**](https://i.imgur.com/vauHLF2.png) to get only the sign-up page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: To get only the sign -up page, you can directly create Sign up Azure AD B2C user flow.

Create the **Sign-up user flow**:

[image]

***Now run the user flow:***

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_ruksignup&client_id=ClientID&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

[image]

Directly the Sign-up page will be displayed to create the user:

[image]

If you want to modify the user flow by having sign-up page first and then sign-in page, then you have to make use of custom policy as user flows are predefined.

**Reference:**

[Azure B2C Show Signup Page First in Unified Signup/Signin Flow - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67960865/azure-b2c-show-signup-page-first-in-unified-signup-signin-flow) by Oisín Foley

Comment: also i want to add a link to the login page on this (signup page), how do i do that?